# How to use Steam's old Login UI in 2023?

Tags: steam

Steam updated their login UI a little while back and made it worse with more annoyances, but there was still a way to use the old login UI. All one would have to do was add "-noreactlogin" to the Target in the shortcut properties. That's not working anymore. So, how do I use the old Login UI as of February 3rd, 2023?

Comment: Support for `-noreactlogin` was removed (see [Steam Community discussion](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/SteamClientBeta/discussions/3/3710433479207750727/)). Seems there is no way back to the old UI now.

Comment: @Kagemusha there has to be _something_. I'd even take rolling back the update and preventing it from auto-updating anymore.

Comment: Have you tried that?

Comment: @Joachim I've tried looking into how to rollback the update but nobody seems to know.

Comment: What's the difference between the new and old login UIs?